# Handling Request IDs from Facebook App Request - MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

Question is regards to handling Request IDs from App Request.

Is there any way in the Facebook C# SDK to get an app access token?
This is the public URL to our test app that retrieves an access token that enables us to get app requests without needing full auth.

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID_HERE7&client_secret=APP_SECRET_HERE&grant_type=client_credentials

This provides us with an access token that can be used to get the data from app requests

https://graph.facebook.com/REQUEST_ID?access_token=APP_ACCESSTOKEN

As far as im aware, the SDK only queries www.facebook.com/oauth..... which does not work in this context.

Any help would be appreciated. Our application is being built in MVC3; Otherwise will need to start building this up without the C# SDK.

Thanks

Comment: Managed to get it myself.
Realised the App Access token could be accessed through:

    var client = FacebookClient(APPID, APPSECRET);
    client.AccessToken;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it myself. Realised the App Access token could be accessed through: var client = FacebookClient(APPID, APPSECRET); client.AccessToken